# Tcl fileevent reads what was sent previously

Tags: serial-port, tcl

I'm a fresh tcl user and I've been working on recently on a script, that uses serial port. My greatest problem so far is that I can't effectively read my serial port. 
I'm using fileevent to read, but it catches what was send previously. However if I dont send anything before, it waits for external data and catches it. My code:

```
    global forever

proc read_serial {serial} {

   set msg [read $serial] 
   set listOfLetters [split $msg {} ]
   set serialIPinHex ""

   foreach iChar $listOfLetters { ;#conversion to hex
      scan $iChar "%c" decimalValue
      set hexValue [format "%02X" $decimalValue ]
      set hexValue "0x$hexValue"
      set serialIPinHex "$serialIPinHex $hexValue"
      }
   puts "MCU RESPONSE:      $serialIPinHex"
   global forever
   set forever 1 ;# end event loop

}

set serial [open com1 r+]
fconfigure $serial -mode "19200,n,8,1"
fconfigure $serial -blocking 0 -buffering none
fconfigure $serial -translation binary -encoding binary
fileevent $serial readable [list read_serial $serial ]

global forever
puts -nonewline $serial \x31\xce
flush $serial
delay 10
vwait forever
flush $serial
close $serial
```

The effect is "MCU RESPONSE:   x31 xce", while it should await for sth to come by serial (in my understanding). I'm sure there is no echo function on the other end. Thanks in advance for your help. I hope my bug is not embarassing, I spend last few hours looking for it...

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to note about serial ports is that they are ***slow***. Really slow. A modern computer can run round the block three times before a serial port has passed one character over (well, metaphorically). That means you're going to get characters coming *one at a time* and you've got to deal with that.

You're advised to use `read $serial 1` and to append that to a buffer you are keeping, or write your code to handle a single byte at a time. If you were using line-oriented messaging, you could take advantage of `gets`'s good behaviour in non-blocking mode (the `fblocked` command is designed to support this), but `read` isn't quite so friendly (since it knows nothing about record separators).

Don't worry about missing a byte if you use `read $serial 1`; if there's one left, your callback will get called again immediately to deal with it.